# Access external script in meteor blaze Template.events

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have this in my client/templates/main.html:

```
<head>
    <title>app boil</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quickblox/2.4.0/quickblox.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

So I am calling the quickblox api. This provides a QB object.

I have now client/templates/quickblox/quickbloxcall.js which has this code:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './quickbloxcall.html'

Template.quickbloxcall.onRendered(function () {
    console.log(QB.createSession);
});


Template.quickbloxcall.events({
    'submit .quickblox-form'(event) {
        var user = {
            id: 4448514,
            name: 'chatuserweb1',
            login: 'chatuserweb1',
            pass: 'chatuserweb1'
        };

        QB.createSession({login: user.login, password: user.pass}, function(err, res) {
            if (res) {
                QB.chat.connect({userId: user.id, password: user.pass}, function(err, roster) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {

                        /*
                         *  (Object) roster - The user contact list
                         *  roster = {
                         *    '1126541': {subscription: 'both', ask: null},        // you and user with ID 1126541 subscribed to each other.
                         *    '1126542': {subscription: 'none', ask: null},        // you don't have subscription but user maybe has
                         *    '1126543': {subscription: 'none', ask: 'subscribe'}, // you haven't had subscription earlier but now you asked for it
                         *  };
                         */

                    }
                });
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

In above code, when I submit form, I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSession' of undefined(…)
```

So this means that the QB object is not accessible inside Template.quickblox.events submit event handler.

However in console.log() I get this:

```
function (params, callback) {
    this.auth.createSession(params, callback);
  }
```

So this means that the Template.quickbloxcall.onRendered is properly loading the QB object.

How do I access this external script in Template.quickblox.events?

Comment: Have you tried [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)?

Comment: Why don't you use the NPM version of Quickblox? maybe it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing on the console does confirm that `QB.createSession` exists. But see that within that `createSession` call *is a call to **another** `createSession`!*

That is, I think you'll find that `this.auth` inside `Qb.createSession` is the object that's `undefined`, and the unavailable `createSession` belongs to `auth` (undefined), not `QB` (defined).

This will happen if you haven't run `QB.init` before calling `QB.createSession`. `init` is explained a bit in [the QuickBlox JavaScript SDK docs here](https://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Initialize_framework).